# Code generated with scalameta is not recognized by intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalameta

I'm trying to create a scalameta annotation, that will define a new case class inside of an existing object.

my goal is to transform:

```
object MyObj {
  case class A()
}
```

into:

```
object MyObj {
  case class A()
  case class B(b: Int, bb: Int)
}
```

for that I created the following annotation:

```
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.meta._

class schema extends StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    val q"..$mods object $ename extends $template" = defn

    val generatedClass: Defn.Class =
      q"""
         case class B(b: Int, bb: Int)
       """

    //the stats that were defined in the annotated object
    val existingStats: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Stat] = template.stats.get

    //new stats
    val stats = Some(existingStats :+ generatedClass)

    //the new template
    val newT = template.copy(stats=stats)

    val res =
      q"""
         ..$mods object $ename extends $newT
       """

    println("============== result ==============")
    println("res: " +res)
    println("====================================")
    res
  }
}
```

and this main class to test it:

```
object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello")

    val b = new MyObj.B(2,22)
    val q = MyObj.A()
    println(b)

  }
}


@schema
object MyObj {
  case class A()
}
```

When I compile and and run the main class, the code behaves as expected.
during compile it prints:

```
============== result ==============
res: object MyObj {
  case class A()
  case class B(b: Int, bb: Int)
}
====================================
```

and after running the code:

```
Hello
B(2,22)
```

---

My problem is when I try to work with this code with intellij.
The code compiles and run from intellij, but the new class `B` can't be recognized, and therefore non of the code completion and hints don't work

[image]

I'm using the latest intellij and scala plugin

---

I've uploaded the full project to git:
https://github.com/lev112/scalameta_intellij/tree/master

This is the first time I'm trying to use scalameta, and I'm trying to understand if it's a bug in intellij, or am I doing something wrong

Comment: I haven't tried your particular, but last time I used Intellij with scala.meta, when changing the scala plugin to use the nightly development version, most things worked. You can change the plugin update channel in the intellij settings.

Answer (score 1):

Just like with old-style macros, the scalameta code needs to be defined in a separate compilation unit so that they get compiled first and can then be invoked while compiling the other sources.

Thanks to https://www.michaelpollmeier.com/2016/12/01/scalameta-code-generation-tutorial